# how to bypass google 2 factor auth for sending email from third party application?

Tags: email, gmail

When our workspace added two factor auth, some of application we developed have some issues in sending mails using those accounts. It showed an error like this "Application Specific password required".

[image]

How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked up for the issue online and found out that the issue can be solved using the app password.

steps to follow :

1. Select your profile icon in the upper-right corner of Gmail, then select Manage Google Account.
2. Select Security in the left sidebar.
3. Select App passwords under the Signing into Google section. You're then asked to confirm your Gmail login credentials.
4. Under Select app, choose Mail or Other (Custom name), then select a device.
5. Select Generate.
6. Your password appears in a new window. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the process, then select Done.

7.Use this 16 char password for your app and it will work fine.

please refer : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhy-you-may-need-an-app-password